# Is there any time-wise split function to a large .CSV column contains multiple strings?

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, pycharm, dataset

I have CSV file and I need to **split** specific column's strings by char = '|||'
so when I use the iterative way **it works** but takes **too much time** to run:

```
for i in range(dataset.shape[0]): #### 9000 Rows
    col = dataset.iloc[i, 1].split('|||')
```

Do you have any other time-wise solution?
[Dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSha2.png)

I need to split posts column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try loading the CSV file using NumPy's [loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or [genfromtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) functions. NumPy will be much faster than a for loop.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("myfile.csv", delimiter="|||")
# Example to access column number 27
data[:, 27]
```

---

EDIT

If you're looking to split an array of strings by a specific delimiter, you can try using [np.char.split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.split.html).

Example

```
split_columns = np.char.split(dataset[:, 1], sep=',')
```